# jQuery get index not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
console.log($('li.pagination').index('[data-page=5]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="0"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="1"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="2"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="3"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="4"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="5"><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="6"><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="7"><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="8"><a href="#">9</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="9"><a href="#">10</a></li>
```

Anyone can please tell me why it returning -1 instead of index How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `$('li.pagination[data-page=5]').index()`.

Answer (score 0):

The main intention of `index()` method in jquery is to Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

So in your case you are giving a selector string instead of jquery object as a parameter to index method

You can make the selector to a jquery object by enclosing selector into a `$()` mehod

If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

```js
console.log($('li.pagination').index($('[data-page=5]')));

console.log($('li.pagination').index($('li.pagination[data-page=5]')));

console.log($('li.pagination[data-page=5]').index());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="0"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="1"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="2"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="3"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="4"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="5"><a href="#">6</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="6"><a href="#">7</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="7"><a href="#">8</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="8"><a href="#">9</a></li>
<li class="pagination active" data-page="9"><a href="#">10</a></li>
```

Comment: Because `index` is zero-based, it should return 6.

Comment: @Tushar it is in the 5th possition of $('li.pagination') array of matched elements. and if they want it to be six I had added your comment also into the snippet Thanks.